# When do the eigenvectors of a Laplacian matrix form a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, laplacian, spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

Eigenvectors do not always form a basis. When do the eigenvectors of a Laplacian matrix form a basis? When the associated adjacency matrix is symmetric? Why?

Answer (score 1):

I assume we are talking about a [graph Laplacian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix).

This is defined as
$$L_{i,j} := \begin{cases}
  \deg(v_i) & \mbox{if}\ i = j \\
         -1 & \mbox{if}\ i \neq j\ \mbox{and}\ v_i \mbox{ is adjacent to } v_j \\
          0 & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
where the $v_i$'s are the vertices in the graph.

This Laplacian matrix is a symmetric matrix. (This assumes that if $v_i$ is adjacent to $v_j$, then $v_j$ is adjacent to $v_i$, which you have stated.)

By the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Hermitian_maps_and_Hermitian_matrices) for [symmetric matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix#Real_symmetric_matrices), this Laplacian matrix is diagonalisable, i.e. it has an eigenvector basis.

Comment: I have a question: On the cited wiki page I read "Every row sum and column sum of L is zero." But what if a vertex has a loop? This is not reflected in the adjacency matrix but in the degree matrix. So, the corresponding row sum is not zero but $2$.

Comment: @amsmath Fair enough. Still, the Laplacian is symmetric, so the diagonalizability result still holds.

Comment: Sure. But that's not my problem. It's not related to the question, I am sorry. So, the statement on the wiki page is false?

Comment: @KennyWong Can you link us to a proof that shows that a diagonalisable matrix has an eigenvector basis?

Comment: @amsmath Which statement are you saying is false?

Comment: @nbro The spectral theorem link *does* contain a proof. You use the fundamental theorem of algebra to infer that $L$ has at least one eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ with eigenvector $v_1$. Then you consider the **orthorgonal completement** of the subspace generated by $v_1$. Because $L$ is symmetric, $L$ maps this orthogonal complement onto itself, i.e. it makes sense to talk about the "restriction of $L$ to this orthogonal complement".

Comment: Then you apply the fundamental theorem of algebra to this orthogonal complement to find a second eigenvalue $\lambda_2$ with eigenvector $v_2$ that is in this orthogonal complement (i.e. $v_2$ is orthogonal to $v_1$). Now consider an even smaller subspace: the orthogonal complement of the span of $v_1$ and $v_2$, and repeat...

Comment: @KennyWong I cite it again: "Every row sum and column sum of L is zero." This should be false in case there are loops.

Comment: @amsmath I think in that case, we would subtract $2$ from the relevant diagonal element. (i.e. we define $L = D - A$, where $D$ is the degree matrix and $A$ is the adjacency matrix, and if there is a loop, then the $2$ in $D$ will cancel out the $2$ in $A$. The formula I quoted in my answer will then not be applicable.)

Comment: @KennyWong But in the wikipedia definition of the adjacency matrix the diagonal is zero.